# arguments of a function keep the value

Tags: c

I m pretty new to C so i need some help with functions.
My question is how can i make a variable i insert into a function keep the value it gets after going through the function ? 
To be more specific lets say i have a function called var(a), with a as argument and when the function finishes, a has the value 15.
So i call the function like this, var(b), but i initialize b with 0 earlier.
And after the execution of the function i want b to have the value 15.
If anyone could help me with a way to do that i would be very pleased.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Search for "pass by reference".

Comment: ... or `a=var(a);` with the function returning the new computed value.

Comment: @101010 There is no pass by reference in C.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab There are no references in C, however there's passing by reference to a function.

Comment: @101010 Technically, it is a simulation of pass by reference.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab "Technically" the term ["pass by reference"](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language:Terms:Pass_by_reference) has nothing to do with C++ references.

Comment: @101010 From your link: "C does not directly support pass by reference because it always uses pass by value, but a programmer can implement pass by reference by passing a pointer to the variable that the programmer wants passed by reference."

Comment: @tourniquet_grab Again, passing by reference doesn't mean passing a reference. The quote that you posted supports my claim :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, all functions are pass by value.  That means that variables used as arguments to a function cannot be changed when the function returns.

You can get around that by passing the **address** of a variable to a function, and declaring the function to take a pointer to a particular type.  Then inside of the function, you can dereference the pointer and change what the pointer points to, i.e. the variable in the calling function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int *a)
{
    *a = 15;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    func1(&x);
    printf("x=%d\n",x);
}
```

Output:

```
x=15
```

Comment: @AndreiPopa Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

Save the returning value back to the variable passed (as suggested by Weather Vane)

```
a = var(a);
```

Pass the variable's address, instead of the variable (use pointers)

```
// calling function
var(&a);

// function definition
void var(int* a) {
    *a = 15;
}
```